# Actionscript Event MOUSE_OVER/MOUSE_OUT not working properly

Tags: actionscript-3

I am new to action script.  I am trying to write a mouse out and over event for separate images.  I want to display one image at a time by using mouseover mouse out events that call methods.   The problem I am having is that the mouseover/out only displays one image.  When I try to mouse over/out on a new image the image does not change, but the output displays a trace which means the event is being called.  I am utilizing goToAndStop() method for each of my frames in my movie clip.

Below is one of my methods:

```
 function onOutTest(e:MouseEvent) {
        trace("onOutTest")
        overlay.visible=false;
    }

 function onOverTest(e:MouseEvent) {
        trace("onOverTest");
        addChild (overlay);
        overlay.gotoAndStop (1);
    }
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: What objects have you attached the listeners to?

Comment: Hi, I created three instances in flash and set their names in the property window.  So, for example,
   test.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOverTest );
   
   test.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOutTest);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change it:

```
addChild(overlay);

function onOutTest(e:MouseEvent) {
    trace("onOutTest")
    overlay.visible = false;
}

function onOverTest(e:MouseEvent) {
    trace("onOverTest");
    overlay.visible = true;
    overlay.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```